# How to use object url in audio src

Tags: reactjs, blob, html5-audio, createobjecturl

I am making a audio player using

```
<audio src={audioSrc}>
```

tag.

When I get the audio file, it was a binary file(`blob` below) so I created a blob with it.

```
let test = new Blob(blob, {type: 'audio/mp3'};
```

And then created an object url

```
let objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(test);
```

This `objUrl` looks like `blob:https://xxxxx` and when I pass this string to `<audio src={objUrl}/>`, I cannot hear anything.

I was wondering if I have to convert this url to make it available in audio tag.

Can I get an advice for this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the `Blob` constructor is an array. MDN describes it like this:

> An Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, USVString objects, or a mix of any of such objects, that will be put inside the Blob. USVString objects are encoded as UTF-8.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#parameters

Maybe creating your blob like this already solves the problem:

```
let test = new Blob([ blob ], { type: 'audio/mp3' });
```

Another problem I could think of is that the binary data has a different mimeType other than `'audio/mp3'` which could cause the audio element to give up decoding the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another prop `autoplay`

```
<audio  src={URL.createObjectURL(test)} autoplay/>
```

Comment: Hello. thanks for the suggestion. but why do you think autoplay will make it work?